# Can we deploy logstash instance to elastic cloud?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elastic-cloud

I have a logstash config file that fetches some data from MySQL DB with crone job and indexes on my ElasticSearch cluster, I need to deploy that logstash instance, question is, does the ES Cloud allows deployment of such logstash instance, I couldn't find any information on that, If not, how can I deploy that instance anywhere on any server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Logstash in Elastic Cloud, if you need a logstash instance you will need to run it elsewhere and configure it to send to your elasticsearch instance on elastic cloud.

After you choose where to run Logstash you can install following the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html) and [configure it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/connecting-to-cloud.html) to send data to Elastic cloud.